# Simple optimization trick

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, optimization

> Let $f,g:X\to\Bbb R$ be two functions where $X$ is any set. Then
>   $$
>   \left|\sup_x f(x) - \sup_x g(x)\right|\leq \sup_x|f(x) - g(x)|.
> $$

This fact is fairly easy to prove, but it seems to be a rather well-known trick, so I am looking for a reference that contains it.

Comment: As I know you speak Russian, there is a book Васин, Морозов "Теория игр и модели математической экономики". Lemma 2.2., page 23

Comment: $||f||=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ is a norm (if f is finite).

Comment: @Nimza: thanks, perhaps I should have specified that ideally it is a reference in English :)

Comment: @CutieKrait: I think, rather $\|f\| = \sup_x|f(x)|$ is a norm, the one you wrote can take negative values.

Comment: yep. correcte‌d

Comment: @CutieKrait: after you corrected, I don't see how does it apply to my case :)

Comment: @Ilya I didn't read any book on games theory in english, but I think that one can find this lemma in such a book before the main theorem of the theory of continuous games.

Comment: sorry they it is pseudo norm. also $|\sup_{x\in X}{f(x)}|$ is a pseudo-norm which is dominated by previous one. now proving your inequlity can be simplified to proving the domination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that this fact appears as A.3 Proposition in the book ["Adaptive Markov Control Processes" by O. Hernandez-Lerma](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387969667), which in turn cites ["Foundations of Non-stationary Dynamic Programming with Discrete Time Parameter"](http://www.springer.com/business+&+management/operations+research/book/978-3-540-04956-2) by K. Hinderer.