# Proof of a simple optimisation trick

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I found this nice result in this question:
[Simple optimization trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348862/simple-optimization-trick),
where the author claims it is easy to prove. How would the proof look like?

> Let $f,g:X\to\Bbb R$ be two functions where $X$ is any set. Then
>   $$
>   \left|\sup_x f(x) - \sup_x g(x)\right|\leq \sup_x|f(x) - g(x)|.
> $$

Comment: It would be easier for the reader if you copied the inequality you want proof of into your question, so one doesn't have to follow the link to see what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need $f, g$ to be bounded, the rest is carefully using definitions.

We have the following result
$$\sup_x (f+g) \le \sup_x f + \sup_x g \tag{1}$$

$$\text{Proof: }\qquad f \le \sup_x f, \quad g \le \sup_x g \implies f+g \le \sup_x f+ \sup_x g.$$

Now using $(1)$:
$$\sup_x f = \sup_x \left((f-g) + g \right)\le \sup_x (f-g) + \sup_x g \le \sup_x \lvert f-g \rvert + \sup_x g$$

So we have $\sup_x f - \sup_x g \le \sup_x \lvert f-g \rvert $.  We can swap $f, g$ to also get $\sup_x g - \sup_x f \le \sup_x \lvert f-g \rvert $.  Together these give us the desired 
$$\left|\sup_x f(x) - \sup_x g(x)\right|\leq \sup_x \lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert.
 $$